# Wrapping up Tefilin to form dove's wings

Tags: minhag, tefilin

[Gemara Shabbos 49a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14314&st=&pgnum=98&hilite=) mentions a story about Elisha Baal Kenafayim who was saved by his Tefilin turning into dove's wings. [Magen Avraham Orach Chaim 28:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=133) says the Minhag is to wrap the Tefilin like wings. How would you wrap your Tefilin like wings? Is this a Minhag that is still practiced?

Comment: Isn't it like this http://www.chabadbytheocean.com/media/images/128/IFjc1286033.jpg

Comment: Perhaps? How does that look like wings? Is this the common way people do it?

Comment: Wings = two large bumps on either side. That's at least how I've always understood it.

Comment: Perhaps you are correct. However I am not clear if that is accurate or if there is some other way to wrap it up as wings.

Answer (score 7):

It is. See [the Moroccan Way of wrapping tefillin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRcHSJFUOfE) from about 2 mins in. The commentary is in French but the pictures are sufficient even if you don't understand French.

I have seen some of my British friends in the UK do it this way too.

Comment: It appears some Jeckes wrap their tefillin shel rosh similarly: http://www.kayj.net/media/kunena/attachments/65/KanfeiYonah.jpg