# Did Elisha get his tefillin back?

Tags: tefilin, agada-stories-legends, maseches-shabbos, birds

The story of אלישע בעל כנפים (Elisha-the-man-of-the-wings) is told on [Shabbos 130a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=130&format=pdf):

> דא"ר ינאי תפילין צריכין גוף נקי כאלישע בעל כנפים [...] ואמאי קרו ליה
>   אלישע בעל כנפים שפעם אחת גזרה מלכות הרשעה גזרה על ישראל שכל המניח
>   תפילין על ראשו יקרו את מוחו והיה אלישע מניח תפילין ויצא לשוק וראהו
>   קסדור אחד רץ מלפניו ורץ אחריו כיון שהגיע אצלו נטלן מראשו ואחזן בידו
>   א"ל מה בידך אמר לו כנפי יונה פשט את ידו ונמצאו בה כנפי יונה לפיכך היו
>   קוראין אותו בעל כנפים
>
> For R. Jannai said: Tefillin demand a pure body, like
>   Elisha-the-man-of-the-wings. [...] And why is he called 'the man-of-the-wings'?
>   Because the wicked State once proclaimed a decree against Israel that
>   whoever donned tefillin should have his brains pierced through; yet
>   Elisha put them on and went out into the streets. A [quaestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaestor) saw him:
>   he fled before him, and the latter gave pursuit. As he overtook him,
>   he [Elisha] removed them from his head and held them in his hand,
>   'What is that in your hand?' he demanded, 'The wings of a dove,' was
>   his reply. He stretched out his hand and the wings of a dove were
>   found therein. Hence he is called 'Elisha-the-man-of-the-wings.'

(*[halakhah.com Soncino translation](http://halakhah.com/rst/moed/12e%20-%20Shabbos%20-%20130a-157b.pdf)*)

<sup><sub>See Tosfos and other commentators there for discussion as to the permissibility/obligation that Elisha had to risk his life for tefillin.</sub></sup>

Did the tefillin really turn into dove's wings, or was it just an illusion that fooled the quaestor? If they really *did* turn into dove's wings, did they turn back into tefillin after?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41215/5323

Comment: ..and if they did turn back into tefillin, were they kosher for use?

Answer (score 1):

The Ateres Yehoshua (רב יהושע קרלנשטיין) offers a unique perspective on the Sugya: The wings never turned back to Tefilin because Hashem doesn't perform miracles without purpose. He also offers an insightful explanation for the enduring moniker "Elisha, Man of Wings," a distinction rarely granted to other sages who experienced miraculous events. Elisha's name endured to ensure that no one would misconstrue the miracle as a mere illusion. Instead, it served as a reminder that he was indeed left with the wings while his Tefilin were lost, solidifying the authenticity of the divine intervention.