# Kanfei Yonah – Above or Below the Bayit

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilin

I have seen two basic styles of wrapping tefillin up 'al kanfei yonah. [The first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk4ue.jpg), which I've seen mainly among the older generation is to put the kesher (knot) below the bayit with the loop in the retzuah folded over the ma'abarta. [The second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa3p8.jpg), which is more common among the younger generation (and all Lubavitchers I've seen) is the reverse, with the kesher **above** the bayit and the retzuah folded **below** the ma'abarta.

Are there any sources which discuss either approach

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22403/759

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the custom of Chabad, it is discussed in Aruch HaShulchan, Orach Chaim, 28:8. It explains there are those with the custom to place the 'Dalet' above the ma'abarta and not below because it is from one of G-d's names and it isn't becoming to place it underneath. If I locate a clear reason for placing it underneath, I'll, bli neder, post it.

It's worth mentioning in this discussion the in regard to placing the knot of the 'Dalet' above, the Lubavitcher Rebbe is recorded as emphasizing that similarly, the straps should not cover the knot when wrapping the wings. I believe that was in Sefer HaMelech b'Mesibato. I can't recall the exact page.